# where may i find an anylogic guide about population of agents?

Tags: anylogic

I'm learning the program and i'd like to know more about the use and the functions regarding the whole population of an agent and not only the agent type.Suggestions?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AnyLogic Help](https://anylogic.help) is the best resource which also specifically covers [population](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/agentbased/agent-population.html#agent-population-properties) properties.